# Find the curvature of a curve given by it's implicit equation

Tags: differential-geometry

Please help me solve this:

Find the curvature of a curve given by it's implicit equation:

$ F(x,y) = 0 $

Now, I thought of solving this by converting it to a parametric equation, but I have no idea how to do so. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose this does define a smooth parametric curve $x = X(s),\; y = Y(s)$ parametrized by arc length $s$ in the neighbourhood of a point $(x_0, y_0) = (X(0), Y(0))$.  Differentiating the equation $F(X(s),Y(s))=0$ twice and using the chain rule (and using subscript notation for partial derivatives)

$$ \eqalign{F_1(X,Y) X' &+ F_2(X,Y) Y' = 0\cr
            F_{11}(X,Y) X'^2 &+ 2 F_{12}(X,Y) X' Y' + F_{22}(X,Y) Y'^2 + F_1(X,Y) X'' + F_2(X,Y) Y'' = 0\cr}$$
Since the parameter is arc length, the velocity vector $V =[X',Y']$ has length $1$ and is the unit tangent vector, i.e. 
$$ X'^2 + Y'^2 = 1$$
and differentiating this gives us $$X' X'' + Y' Y'' = 0$$

The curvature is then $\kappa = |V'| = \sqrt{X''^2 + Y''^2}$.

Eliminating $X'$ and $Y'$ from the equations is rather tedious, but  should give us

$$ \kappa = \frac{\left| F_{11} F_2^2- 2 F_{12} F_1 F_2 + F_{22} F_1^2\right|}{(F_1^2 + F_2^2)^{3/2}}$$

Answer (score -1):

WE can find  [Implicit form of Curvature](http://u.math.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/goldman05.pdf) by implicit differentiation in the plane

Formula (3.1)

Comment: Any chance you could give me through this exercise? I'm really really lost and tomorrow's my exam

Comment: The simplest is a circle given in my reply as  reference. For $x^2+y^2-R^2=0$. It gives $\kappa= -1/R$ ; If you take $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2-R^2=0$ you will get either sign of $ 1/R $ depending upon  $h,k$. I did not calculte it though, even if simple.

Answer (score -1):

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature

"Implicit curve" under "Curvature of plane curves"